# Flatten option is not available in Blender 2.92

Tags: edit-mode, tools

I am following along a [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/1jHUY3qoBu8?t=2945) at the mark 49:05 time, he is using <kbd>F3</kbd> to open Search menu, and types **FLATTEN**.

When I do the same, the search results disappear, and I have no FLATTEN option.

[image: Blender 2.92 has no FLATTEN option in search menu]

I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> as mentioned [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools/flatten.html) but that did nothing.

How can I access the Flatten option?

Answer (score 3):

Only exist if you enable the *Loop Tools* addon from *Edit > Preferences > Add Ons > Mesh: Loop-Tools*.

It seems like the  <kbd>F3</kbd> sShortcut to use *LoopTools* functions changed in 2.90.

*Select Faces > Orientation Normal*, right-click > *Looptools* or <kbd>N</kbd> Menu *Edit > Looptools*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about any flatten option but if you have mesh:looptools enabled in preferences you can select your faces and then right click->looptools->flatten to get the result it seems you are looking for.